# parent child relation PHP

Tags: php

how can i create a parent child relation. For example i have a variable where the data is sort by the category.

what i am trying here is how can i write a function which can search both and parent function both.

for example -- if someone search for **CATEGORY1** he should retun back all the names like -- **john, christoffer hansen, jonatthon orkar mej, fredrik hanvensson**.

But if someone search for **jonatthon** he should get only **jonatthon** in return.

so all the data is stored in the variable named $store_var, which if i print it i get like so ---

```
Array
(
    [CATEGORY1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1002
                    [name] => john
                    [category] => CATEGORY1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1121
                    [name] => christoffer hansen
                    [category] => CATEGORY1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4529
                    [name] => jonatthon orkar mej
                    [category] => CATEGORY1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4309
                    [name] => fredrik hanvensson
                    [category] => CATEGORY1
                )

        )

    [CATEGORY2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3412
                    [name] => johanna Ottenfelt 
                    [category] => CATEGORY2
                )

            [1] => Array
```

any advice will be really really appreciable. thanks in advanced .

Comment: Where do you have the data (PHP/MySQL)? how is the data stored?

Comment: have a look at this code: http://codepad.org/987KIW8b. I'll fully implement it on my local machine.

Comment: @XicoXperto that's not important. Just take it as data structure question.

Comment: just write that code -http://codepad.org/HdRu4N41
and my php editor showed that there are also builtin functions like `array_keys`, `array_search`, `array_filter` :) you can easliy implement them - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: @marmeladze thanks a lot for your help, but the question still remain, what happen when i just search for a name, it should search for the category and for the name at the same time !

Answer (score 1):

This is the function for first part of your question.

```
function search_parent($param, $arr, $att) {
    $result = "";
    if(array_key_exists($param, $arr)) {

    for ($i =0; $i<sizeof($arr[$param]); $i++) {

        $result .= $arr[$param][$i][$att]."<br>";
    }

    }
    $domain = 'Results for:'. $param."<br>"; 
    return $domain.$result;

}
// echo search_parent('CATEGORY 1', $my, 'name');
// echo search_parent('CATEGORY 2', $my, 'name');
```

The below code also works but when I tried to put them in a function,

```
$first_node = array_keys($my);
foreach ($first_node as $fnk => $fnv) {
    $second_node = array_keys($my[$fnv]);
    foreach ($second_node as $snk => $snv) {
        if (in_array("John", ($my[$fnv][$snv]))) { echo "John exists"; exit(); } ;

    }
}
```

like that,

```
function search_child($param, $arr) {
$result = "";

$first_node = array_keys($arr);
foreach ($first_node as $fnk => $fnv) {
    $second_node = array_keys($arr[$fnv]);
    foreach ($second_node as $snk => $snv) {
        if (in_array($param, ($arr[$fnv][$snv]))) { 
            $result = $param. " exists"; }
       else {
            $result = $param. "does not exist in given array";
     }

    }
}
return $result;
}
//$p = 'Mile';
//echo search_child($p, $my);
```

it didn't work. Probably I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is. Despite all successful/unsuccessful results, this is not a good solution, but just "save a day".